# What is the shortcut for toggle between Design and Source tab in Netbeans (java) window?

Tags: netbeans

How to go to source tab from design tab in netbeans by shortcut. I mean toggle between the two by shortcut. Is there any way?

Answer (score 6):

There actually is a shortcut, you can switch tabs like Source, Desing, History etc. with Ctrl+Alt+PgUp/PgDown
Now if any1 knows how to change this to something simple, that would be a good thing.

Source:https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/two_hidden_netbeans_keyboard_shortcust

Answer (score 0):

The only way to switch between the source code and the GUI builder is to click the tab corresponding to which view you need. There are no shortcuts to the extent of my knowledge.

I am using NetBeans 7.4.